# PHP Socket server run as service

Tags: php, sockets

I have created the PHP socket server and started that in localhost ( 127.0.0.1) through command prompt. i.e

C:\xampp\php\php server.php

this working fine in localhost.but my problem is i have to run this server.php file in the domain server. i have copied the server.php file to the web host directory (http://example.com/server.php) and changed the ip address to the domain ip address in php file. Now the problem is when i run the file in the browser like

http://www.example.com/server.php

the socket server starts fine and within 5 minutes it automatically stopped by the browser(Error 500).
how can i run that server.php file through command prompt. help needed.

thanks.

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the server?

Comment: don't you have CLI possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start a server by calling it over HTTP. Assuming, you're using Apache, this is what happens: an Apache worker thread picks up your request and starts the underlying PHP script. Then, depending on your `php.ini` settings, the script is terminated after a certain amount of time (`max_execution_time`).

In order for this to work the way you expected it to work, the PHP script would have to fork itself *and* start a new session (via [`posix_setsid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setsid.php)). This would require the worker threads to run as root, though which is an *absolute security issue.*

If you have access to the server (via SSH) it's possible to start the server just as you would locally with the exception that - if you don't have root privileges - the PHP script cannot listen on privileged ports (ports <= 1024).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to launch the php script as a server, and when you access it using your web browser, the server called is the http server (apache or whatever).

The http server then call the php module which launch your script. As the request has a maximum execution time, you can't make it run as a server !

What you may do, given you have sufficient right on your server, is to create a php script that will launch the server, using server-side program execution.

Comment: i got it working by the following code

<?php
  echo exec("server.php");
?>

thanks for help. It helped me very much.....